# Checking how increment operation works in c

Tags: c, increment

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a,b,c,d;
    a=5;
    scanf("%d",&d);
    b=(++a)+(++a);
    printf("changed declared value = %d operated value = %d\n",a,b);
    c=(++d)+(++d);
    printf("changed input value= %d operated value= %d ",d,c);
    return 0;
}
```

variable a is assigned value 5 and d is given value 5 from user. Then same increment operation is performed but output is different.
Can someone explain why this is happening. Tried both cases on same compiler.

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4qik.png)

Comment: Your code does not  guarantee successful input from user, because you ignore the return value of scanf.

Comment: Please include text output as formatted txt into your question.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418 which applies to all textual information.

Comment: Please, please, *please*, **please** [look at the warnings emitted by your compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/T376Eb3WW).  "warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point] b=(++a)+(++a);"

Comment: The duplicate link explains why the result is generally undefined. Yet it is interesting why it is different here. The compiler might simply take the value `5` that it know for variable `a` and do optimized calculation while for `d` it must use the value from your input.

Comment: @Gerhardh I accept your opinion, while I disagree. Also, your comment probably undermines OPs chance to really understand the concept of undefined behaviour.